# ModuleNotFoundError import seaborn as sns

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

When I type `import seaborn as  sns` on jupyter and on VScode, it always happens `ModuleNotFoundError`.

I have already did `pip install seaborn` in my terminal.

Has someone a solution? Thank you in advance

PS

I have already done install seaborn in terminal

```
pip install seaborn
Requirement already satisfied: seaborn in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (0.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (1.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=2.2 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from seaborn) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.2->seaborn) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=0.23->seaborn) (1.16.0)
```

Numpy and pandas work.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ6wI.png)

Comment: In your Jupyter Notebook, try the command `!pip freeze` in a new cell and run it. Does the output include `seaborn`?

Comment: Yes, there is. scikit-image==0.17.2
scikit-learn @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/scikit-learn_1611079733572/work
scipy @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/scipy_1604304777848/work
seaborn==0.11.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0

Comment: Does this happen also outside of VSCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
conda install seaborn
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge seaborn
```

Comment: I would discourage using conda next to pip as the two installers do not always work well with each other. This suggestion would just mess things up even further.

Comment: Thank you! I have upgrated pip and install pip install seaborn, I solved it. Thank you !